# Video Compression ios : Reduce the size of a video usin AVAssetWriter

Tags: ios, video, compression, reduce, avassetwriter

I am Successful in encoding a series of image captured by AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer of AVFoundation Framework into a Video using AVAssetWriter and AVAssetWriterInput.

**But the size of the video is too large, Can anyone of you suggest me a tutorial or atleast a direct me 
in this case or give me the correct Video output Settings for video compression.**

I am using the following VideoOutputSetting.

```
videoOutputSettings = @{
                          AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecH264,
                          AVVideoWidthKey: [NSNumber numberWithInt:width],
                          AVVideoHeightKey: [NSNumber numberWithInt:height],
                          AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey: @{
                                  AVVideoAverageBitRateKey: [NSNumber numberWithInt:bitrate],
                                  AVVideoMaxKeyFrameIntervalKey: @(150),
                                  AVVideoProfileLevelKey: AVVideoProfileLevelH264BaselineAutoLevel,
                                  AVVideoAllowFrameReorderingKey: @NO,
                                  AVVideoH264EntropyModeKey: AVVideoH264EntropyModeCAVLC,
                                  AVVideoExpectedSourceFrameRateKey: @(30),
                                  AVVideoAverageNonDroppableFrameRateKey: @(30)
                                  }
                          };
    videoWriterInput = [AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo outputSettings:videoSettings];
    _videoWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = YES;
```

Comment: It seems that "AVVideoAverageBitRateKey: [NSNumber numberWithInt:bitrate]," holds the solution. What bitrate are you setting? How small do you want the video to be?

Comment: i have a set a bitrate of 2000000 but when i reduce the bitrate the quality of video falls i.e i mean to say the video obtained is BLUR

Comment: Okay, so 2 megabits per second, or 2 Mbps. What rate are you targeting?

Comment: my target is to reduce the size of the video without disturbing its quality and even at a low bitrate for say 2048 kb/s

Comment: Please check this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27987879/avassetwriter-outputting-large-file-even-when-applying-compression-settings?answertab=active#tab-top