# How To compress a video to accurate size in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, compression, size

Probably most of you using WhatsApp and you probably know that when you want to send a video to one of your contacts WhatsApp first of all compressing the video to maximum size of 16mb and only afterword it uploads the chosen video to your contact.

what i am trying to do it is simply the same thing using AV Foundation or to be more specific AVAssetExportSession.

here is my code:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {



        NSURL *videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *sourcePath =[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"/output.mov"];
        NSURL *outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:sourcePath];

        [self convertVideoToLowQuailtyWithInputURL:videoURL outputURL:outputURL handler:^(AVAssetExportSession *exportSession)
         {
             if (exportSession.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted)
             {
                 NSLog(@"completed");
             }
             else
             {
                 NSLog(@"error: %@",exportSession.error);
             }
         }];

         [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void)convertVideoToLowQuailtyWithInputURL:(NSURL*)inputURL outputURL:(NSURL*)outputURL handler:(void (^)(AVAssetExportSession*))handler
{

    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:outputURL error:nil];
    AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:inputURL options:nil];

    AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality];
    exportSession.outputURL = outputURL;
    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;

    [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^(void)
     {
         handler(exportSession);
     }];

}
```

this code works wonderful, it takes the video and compressing it really small size.

the problem is when the user try to upload a quite long video with powerful camera the size is not small enough to me.

**What i want to do is actually to compress any video to a limited size
lets say for example to 16Mb like WhatsApp do. 
How can i do that?**

Comment: Go through  the below link 


[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23342964/video-compression-ios-reduce-the-size-of-a-video-usin-avassetwriter?rq=1][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23342964/video-compression-ios-reduce-the-size-of-a-video-usin-avassetwriter?rq=1

Comment: @Ravi in the link you added there is only a settings of how the video will look like after the compress, that is actually the solution but there is lot of code missing and i still don't know how to work with this little piece of code. can you help?

Comment: Meaning 4k and 1080p video will have the same quality in the end? so adaptable compression on whatsapp?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't seems to exist an easy way but AVAssetExportSession has an estimatedOutputFileLenght that could help.
In my code I iterate over different qualities and check if the file size is in the size I want:

```
NSURL * inputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:inputURL options:nil];
    AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = nil;
    for (NSString * string in @[AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality,AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality,AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality]) {
        exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:asset presetName:string];
        exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
        exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4;
        exportSession.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, asset.duration);
        unsigned long long espectedFileSize = exportSession.estimatedOutputFileLength;
        if (espectedFileSize < VIDE_LIMIT) {
            break;
        }

    }
    //Temp file

    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@", [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString], @"video.mov"];
    NSString * filePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    exportSession.outputURL = fileURL;
    [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^(void)
```

Comment: your solution is really really nice, but in fact its exactly the same as i do. The highestQuality is usually bigger then 16mb and the LowQuality is too low for me. see this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/AVFoundationPG.pdf) if you understand how to work with this because i little bit confused inside there.

Comment: AVAssetExportSession is not the only way to achieve that, if you need more control you can use a combination of AVAssetReader/AVAssetWriter, but I never tried. I've found this article that I think it could be helpful for you http://finalize.com/2014/10/21/exporting-a-video-in-ios-to-reduce-size-and-ensure-maximum-client-compatibility/